# Downloading Ubuntu onto a flash drive

Tags: partitioning, usb

So I have two flash drives in, one is running Ubuntu as a live cd and I'm using that to install Ubuntu on the other. I've gone through the download process, clicked on "something else" and now I have to partition my flash drive. I don't know how to do this. What exactly do I do now?

Thank you guys so much! That link helped a lot, I'm just not sure if I have quite the right amount of space partitioned to each thing(I'm using a 14gig flashdrive) but I think I'm close enough. Does it matter if the colors that show how much space is is used are swapped with the ones in the link?

Comment: In the link given by karel there is a detailed process, just be sure to select the appropiate /dev/sdX for the flash drive!

Answer (score 0):

Follow the option for manual partitioning, however be sure that you are operating with the second USB flash device, like /dev/sdb1. Most likely you are booting from the /dev/sda which is installation media, so now add/create a partition on /dev/sdb to install to.